# Welcome to Google+ Hangouts stuck in a loop

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus

### Backstory

I cannot get the hangouts going from Google+, Gmail, or the Chrome desktop app. It also gives me the welcome to Google+ message on my KitKat Nexus 5 in the hangouts app frequently when I open it.

I have tried this on Google Chrome, Firefox, and IE 9-11. I have tried this on Windows 7, Windows 8, Ubuntu 12.04, and Ubuntu 14.04.

I am also using a Google Apps account on a domain that I own.

### Research

When I look at the Network tab in the Chrome developer tools, I see a bunch of cancelled requests to:

https://talkgadget.google.com/u/0/_/diagnostics/?diagnostics

I also see a get request to:

https://talkgadget.google.com/u/0/talkgadget/_/channel/bind?VER=8&clid=D68284B35E25BDB4&prop=gmail&ec=%5B%22ci%3Aec%22%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C%22chat_wcs_20140501.133050_RC2%22%5D%0A&gsessionid=Ivx_SMp8dVo&RID=rpc&SID=A186B6BA81780E5&CI=0&AID=7&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=u8x7s3x8u6zb&t=2

But it does not have a response and is red inside the developer console.

I've also found [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/Yoy9rs2OmSY) but there was never a solution posted.

Is anyone aware what causes this, or what a the fix could be?